# how to create order with USDT as quantity parameter?

Tags: binance, tradingview-api, binance-api-client, binance-chain

I am trying to place a futures order through api.
Here is the code below:

```
  bot.futures_create_order(symbol="FLMUSDT",side="BUY",type="MARKET",quantity=12)
```

This code is making order of buying 12 FLM quantity with usdt of 6$ as price of FLM is 0.5 at that time .
But what I want to make order is 12$ usdt as quantity parameter  and whatever the quantity can be get during that market price should be place order.

I want to pass USDT as quantity parameter, The reason for this is, for specific quantity of any token, we need to fetch price to calculate quantity with available balance for trade, this consumes some time, I don't want to waste that time.

Is there any way to make USDT as quantity parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The Python binance is not yet official so the direct answer to your question is not possible buy you can manipulate it mathematically.

price of FLM = $ 0.5

quantity for price($12)  = price / FLM price

### get current price of coin using

> `bot.futures_symbol_ticker(symbol = 'FLMUSDT')`